# How to avoid fatal error of rabbitmq not installed

Tags: php, codeigniter, rabbitmq

I'm using rabbitmq with PhpAmqpLib library for codeigniter and it works fine but I'm working on multiple machines in one machine rabbitmq is installed and another it is not and for some reasons I dont want to install rabbitmq on it.

I'm getting error :

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'stream_socket_client(): unable
>        to connect to tcp://localhost:5672 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>        refused it.
>       )' in F:\xampp\htdocs\v010-commonsocialnetwork\application\third_party\rabbitmq\libraries\vendor\romainrg
>       \codeigniter-php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO.php:130
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 [internal function]: PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->error_handler(2, 'stream_socket_c...', 'F:\xampp
>       \htdocs...', 130, Array)
>       #1 F:\xampp\htdocs\v010-commonsocialnetwork\application\third_party\rabbitmq\libraries\vendor\romainrg
>       \codeigniter-php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO.php(130): stream_socket_client('tcp://localhost
>       ...', 10061, 'No connection c...', 3, 4, Resource id #127)
>       #2 F:\xampp\htdocs\v010-commonsocialnetwork\application\third_party\rabbitmq\libraries\vendor\romainrg
>       \codeigniter-php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection.php(194): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO-
>       >connect()
>       #3 F:\xampp\htdocs\v010-commonsocialnetwork\a in **F:\xampp\htdocs\v010-commonsocialnetwork\application
>       \third_party\rabbitmq\libraries\vendor\romainrg\codeigniter-php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO.php**
>        on line **130**

Is there anything to avoid this error ? background job may not add and execute on that machine but at least not throw this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with try catch its not giving fatal error anymore :)

```
try {
                $CI->load->add_package_path(APPPATH . 'third_party/rabbitmq');
                $CI->load->library('rabbit_mq');
                $CI->load->remove_package_path(APPPATH . 'third_party/rabbitmq');
                $CI->rabbit_mq->push('background_job', json_encode(array('method'=>'check_activity_visibility','data'=>array('ActivityGUID'=>get_detail_by_id($entity_id),'ENVIRONMENT'=>ENVIRONMENT))), TRUE, array('delivery_mode' => 2));
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                // Do nothing
            }
```

Comment: are you sure this is the way to fix it?

Comment: not sure but it works for me now, if find better option I'll definitely go with it :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install RabbitMQ in the other machine(s).

But you have to change the IP you are trying to connect:

```
tcp://localhost:5672
```

should be

```
tcp://rabbitmq_ip_machine:5672
```

Comment: but what if I deploy on server I've to change ip again for server ?

Comment: well, it depends. A good practice  is to use a load-balacer. or you can use always the `rabbitmq` server ip